# Displaying data from a int variable in a rich text box in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have been trying to get a rich text box to display the current cpu usage from a variable I created when I click a button, but does not work when I use .appendText because it is an int could anyone show me how to do this?

```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Can you please rephrase or add more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AppendText`-method only accepts parameters of type `string`. So you have to convert your `int`-variable `.ToString()`.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(yourVariable.ToString());
}
```